# how to integrate two arraylist into one,with their index value

Tags: android, arraylist

i want to add two arraylist into one,so as make it one and display..,in one arraylist ,i m retrieving names from contactlist and in other,i m retriving numbers.by combinig these two i want to show them in to the autocomplete textview.
**MainActivity**

```
Cursor phones = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " ASC");
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
             phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
             name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            System.out.println(phoneNumber);


            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
        //  meMap.put("name1","phno1");
        //  mPeopleList.add(name);
        //  mPeopleList.add(phoneNumber);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> inviteList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for(int i=0;i < name1.size();i++)
            {
                 HashMap    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(name1.get(i).toString());
                map.put("emailID", inviteListRespone.get(i).getEmail());
                inviteList.add(map);
            }
        }
searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
    //String[] from={ Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, phoneNumber};

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,name1);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        ma = new MyAdapter();

        searchText.setThreshold(1);
        searchText.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, you are retrieving phone numbers and names from a database, and you want to show them in a list?

If you want to use an array adapter, which i dont reccommend, your will have to merge your information into a single String, since the layout you are using only contains one textview.

Your code to merge should look something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++) {
   String name = name1.get(i);
   name += " " + phno1.get(i);
}
```

and then pass just the name list to the adapter.

But you could just alter your code to

```
 while (phones.moveToNext()) {
             phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
             name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            System.out.println(phoneNumber);


            name1.add(name + " " + phoneNumber); // changed this
            ...
```

this way you wont have to iterate over the list again.